# pytest-asyncio with singletons causes conflicting event loops

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, pytest-asyncio

I'm using dbus for IPC. In order to have exactly one bus throughout the livetime of my program I'm using a singleton here. For the sake of demonstration I'm connecting to NetworkManager but that could be exchanged. Furthermore, I'm using `asyncio` for the entire project.
This is a minimalistic working example of the module that will highlight the problem described below:

```
import asyncio  # noqa

from dbus_next.aio import MessageBus
from dbus_next import BusType


BUS = None


async def get_bus():
    # Returns a BUS singleton
    global BUS
    if not BUS:
        BUS = await MessageBus(bus_type=BusType(2)).connect()

    return BUS


async def introspect():
    # Get the dbus singleton and call a method on that singleton
    bus = await get_bus()
    return await bus.introspect(
        'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager',
        '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager',
    )
```

I'm using `pytest` with the `pytest-asyncio` plugin for testing which works like charm except for this case.
This is a minimalistic work test module:

```
import pytest

from example import introspect


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_example_first():
    # With only this first call the test passes
    await introspect()


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_example_second():
    # This second call will lead to the exception below.
    await introspect()
```

When I execute that test, I'm getting the following exception indicating that the event loop changed:

```
example.py:22: in introspect
    '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager',
../.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dbus_next/aio/message_bus.py:133: in introspect
    return await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=timeout)
/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py:403: in wait_for
    fut = ensure_future(fut, loop=loop)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

coro_or_future = <Future pending>

    def ensure_future(coro_or_future, *, loop=None):
        """Wrap a coroutine or an awaitable in a future.
    
        If the argument is a Future, it is returned directly.
        """
        if coroutines.iscoroutine(coro_or_future):
            if loop is None:
                loop = events.get_event_loop()
            task = loop.create_task(coro_or_future)
            if task._source_traceback:
                del task._source_traceback[-1]
            return task
        elif futures.isfuture(coro_or_future):
            if loop is not None and loop is not futures._get_loop(coro_or_future):
>               raise ValueError('loop argument must agree with Future')
E               ValueError: loop argument must agree with Future
```

I'm guessing that pytest started an event loop and during module import another event loop was started but I'm not sure. I tried enforcing using the `pytest` or the module event loop using `asyncio.set_event_loop()` but I had no success. The result stayed the same.

Is my assumption correct? How can I either enforce using a global event loop? Alternatively, how should I define the singleton to make this work with `pytest`?

Probably worth noting is that this singleton construct works perfectly fine in the context of the program. It's just the test which I can't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From looking at this, looks like you're using a global variable which connects to something. Persistent connections are bound to an event loop. So if you want to continue using a global variable, the scope of the event loop fixture needs to match the scope of this variable.

I would redefine the event loop fixture to be session scoped, and create a session scoped fixture, depending on the event loop fixture, to initialize this global variable (by just calling `get_bus`, I suppose). The second fixture is required to ensure proper initialization ordering - i.e. that the event loop is set up properly first.

Edit: The documentation of `pytest-asyncio` says that event loops by default are test function scoped. Thus, they are being recreated in for each test. This default behavior can be simply overridden:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def event_loop():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'll give it a try and keep this thread updated!

Comment: Do you have a status update? I tried the event loop to no avail, but I'll double check my variable scope.

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you very much.